# Is it possible to create a word cloud by importing data from an Excel file?

Tags: python, word-cloud

I have no idea.

```
your_list=[]
workbook=openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='crawling.xlsx')
worksheet=workbook.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet")
for i in worksheet.rows:
    page=i[0].value
    your_list.append(page)
```

I don't know what to do first. Is the library to use openpyxl or is it better to just read the document with open function?

I want WordCloud (). Generate (your_list) to be possible
Sorry for the messy code.

Comment: Does the code here work? That is, does `your_list` end up containing the expected list of words? If so, it seems like you're already on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I can use

from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"Youtube04-Eminem.excel", encoding ="latin-1")

pandas lib to read excel file